# Programs "Auto-Locking" to launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, launchpad, do-release-upgrade

I upgraded from 12.04 LTS to 13.10, with do-release-upgrade, and ever since then, I have had issues with programs staying in the launcher without locking them there. Is this intended? If so, how do I shut it off?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen when you install new software or all the time? I think with new software it automatically adds it and you can turn it off somehow but I'll have to look it up. Also when you move the icon up and own in the launcher while you're using a program it will remain there.

Comment: Maybe that is it then, I always move my netbeans icon up under firefox... always have though and this is the first time this has happened. I did notice its mostly netbeans and some other programs, and now that you mention it, I think it is ones I move. As i said though, this must be something new since 12.04, it did not happen to me in that version.

Comment: @duxk.gh you are correct, when I move and icon in 13.10 it locks it there, you should answer with that and I will vote it up, thank you!

Comment: Yeah I had the same "problem". It's one of those features that isn't at all necessary. It only saves you two clicks to lock an icon to the launcher... not worth the annoying consequence.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior when moving the icon of a running application in the launcher. I guess the assumption is that if you care about where the icon is, you want to keep it there.

As far as I know there is no way to turn this feature off. If I'm correct, the only way to solve the problem is to not move around the icon.

Comment: That makes sense though..